# What is the query to update a value in a list of maps in Apache Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra

I have created a table in Cassandra with a column datatype `list<Frozen map<text, text>>`. 
I'm trying to write a query to update a value in this list of maps by filtering the list by a key:value pair but couldn't find it. The only option I have is to extract the whole list using flask python API and filter and update the map key:value and update the whole list back into the table.

Is there any update query statement to update the exact map key:value in the list of maps in Cassandra??

Answer (score 1):

Frozen collections are processed as one distinct value regardless of the number of items in the collection. This means that you cannot update the individual items in your `map` -- you can only overwrite the *whole* `map` collection.

For more info, see [CQL frozen collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html). Cheers!